# How can I calculate the static transform between 2 coordinate frames?

Tags: ros, move-base, frame, static-transform-publisher

I have a list of poses that I'm trying to publish after converting into the 'map' coordinate frame of reference.
I understand that this is done with the help of tf/static_transform_publisher, however I am not sure how to determine the values of the transform.

Is there a standard method for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> How can I calculate the static transform between 2 coordinate frames?

#### Using terminal

Please use `tf_echo` utility from tf package as shown below:

1. [ROS 1](https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Debugging%20tools): `$ rosrun tf tf_echo turtle1 turtle2`
2. [ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Introduction-To-Tf2.html#using-tf2-echo): `$ ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo turtle2 turtle1`

#### Using API inside code

Please use `lookupTransform` from tf package as shown below:

1. [ROS 1](https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29): `listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/turtle1", ros::Time(0), transform);`
2. [ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Writing-A-Tf2-Listener-Cpp.html): `tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(toFrameRel, fromFrameRel, tf2::TimePointZero);`

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! However, I have not yet defined the transform from "map-gt" to "map". I am unsure how to calculate the numbers to correctly transform between the 2 frames

Comment: I suggest improving your question. You said _"I have a list of poses..."_ in your question already. You are either confused or not sharing the complete information with us.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. I have a list of poses in one coordinate frame, I don't yet have their equivalent in the map frame.

Answer (score 0):

Find below some possibilities on how to address your problem:

- Probably is not suitable for the case at your hand, but the transform can be trivial. E.g. if you place a camera (RF with z forward) parallel to the ground, 10cm above a mobile base (RF with x forward), you have a translation of 10cm and a rotation of 90°, thus you can "manually" define your transform. See an example in the [tf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF).
  If you fall into this scenario, thus you probably should edit your robot `urdf` to include the camera-to-base link, and let the [`robot_state_publisher`](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot) do the rest.
- From your answer to [ravi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/32957/ravi), I guess you are able to retrieve the pose of an object (more in general, a point) in the `map-gt` reference frame.
  You should place something in known poses in the `map` reference frame, assuming that you are able to locate the `map` origin in the real world. One option is to measure (yes, with a tape measure, a ruler, or whatever) where they are. Once you have got the same point both in `map` and `map-gt`, you can use an algorithm such as ICP (iterative closest point) to find the transform. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528094/computing-the-3d-transformation-between-two-sets-of-points) some extra info about the algorithm, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120384/iterative-closest-point-icp-implementation-on-python) some possible Python implementations of it.
- If you have access to a camera set up to work in ROS, you could also try to use markers (such as Aruco markers) and the [aruco_ros](https://github.com/pal-robotics/aruco_ros) package to directly get the transform between your RF. Please note that you have to manually place the markers at the origin of each of the two RF and align them with the RF axis, which is very error-prone and could not always be feasible (e.g. if the origin is on the floor and the z-axis points downward).

Hope you can find your way!